# JAXB marshall Properties

Tags: javafx, jaxb, javafx-8

Using JAXB, I cannot figure out how to marshal `Properties`. In particular, I am trying to marshal a `SimpleObjectProperty` but I assume it won't work with other properties either. In some other classes, I was able to manage getters/setters, but that will not work in this case of the `HashMap` of `SimpleObjectProperties`

Here is my code snippet:

```
..
@XmlRootElement(name = "derby")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Derby extends Observable {
    @XmlElement(name = "cars")
    private final ArrayList<Car>                                cars;
    @XmlTransient
    private final ObservableList<Car>                           carsObservable;
    @XmlElement(name = "schedule")
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<Schedule>                scheduleProperty;
    @XmlElement(name = "settings")
    private final HashMap<String, SimpleObjectProperty>         settings;//This is not marshalling correctly
..
```

And here is the output XML snippet:

```
...
<settings>
    <entry>
        <key>track.lanecount</key>
        <value/> //No value???
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>general.cardisplay</key>
        <value/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>track.orientation</key>
        <value/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>general.derbytitle</key>
        <value/>
    </entry>
</settings>
...
```

I am creating the variables and not leaving them uninitialized. I also tested if the settings actually have a value before marshalling, and they do.

The reason I am using `Properties` instead of just the real object I am trying to store is because I want to add listeners to my settings so when a single setting changes, all of the things that rely on it will update automatically.

Comment: Big caveat: I know nothing about JAXB and have never worked with it. However... what you need is to marshal the *contents* of the property. In the JPA world this is done by having the JPA implementation use the get/set methods for accessing data. See [this blog](http://svanimpe.be/blog/properties-jpa.html) or [this one](https://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2014/05/09/one-bean-to-bind-them-all/). Maybe there is some equivalent idea in JAXB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i see you are using **@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)** that means that the class fields are used to marschal / unmarshal values...

you could change it to **@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)** and then put all **@XmlElement** onto the getter of the property.

see documentation for more: [XmlAccessType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html)

your code sipped then look something like this:

```
..
@XmlRootElement(name = "derby")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Derby extends Observable {

    private final ArrayList<Car>                                cars;

    private final ObservableList<Car>                           carsObservable;

    private final SimpleObjectProperty<Schedule>                scheduleProperty;

    private final HashMap<String, SimpleObjectProperty>         settings;//This is not marshalling correctly

    @XmlElement(name = "cars")
    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(final ArrayList<Car> cars) {
        this.cars.clear();
        this.cars.addAll(cars);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "schedule")
    public Schedule getSchedule() {
        return this.scheduleProperty.get();
    }

    public void setSchedule(final Schedule schedule) {
        this.scheduleProperty.set();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "settings")
    public Map<String, Object> getSettings() {
        // do your mapping logic here...
        // convert your HashMap<String, SimpleObjectProperty> to Map<String, Object>
    }

    public void setSettings(final Map<String, Object> settings) {
        // do your mapping logic here...
        // convert your Map<String, Object> to HashMap<String, SimpleObjectProperty>
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public ObservableList<Car> getCarsObservable() {
        return carsObservable;
    }
..
```

Comment: I switched to JSON w/ Jackson by now, but this might have solved the problem at the time.

Comment: ok,... but could you accept this answer it it is ok for you? i know you do not use it anymore but i think there are others out there with the same problem. but it is not a problem if not. have a nice day. thanks